# Couchdb - Is it possible to deactivate the reduce_overflow_error error

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am working on a map/reduce that doesn't return exactly what I am expecting in rereduce cases.

I'd like to debug it but I at least want too see what's in it, so I output a lot of things and Couch returns with a `reduce_overflow_error` each time I run the view.

Is it possible to deactivate this behavior?

I know this is here to prevent developers doing unhealthy views, but if I want to do crap, shouldn't I be allowed to? Especially when debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to modify CouchDB config to disable this restriction.

First way via curl:

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/query_server_config/reduce_limit -d '"false"' -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Second is via local.ini config modification. Just add or modify section as shown below and restart CouchDB service:

```
[query_server_config]
reduce_limit = false
```

Third one is through Futon Configuration page. I suppose, you'd already guessed what parameter should be modified there(;

But is most cases this restriction is reasonable since reduce function should *reduce* output, not make it bigger - that's map function work. For debugging reasons better to enable debug logs - they are really detailed and may show map/reduce/any function output.

Comment: Holy guacamole! I've searched for 'overflow' and 'error' into the Futon Configuration page but never thought of 'limit'. Next time I want debugging I'll try the logs, thanks for the tips.